# Where do minimized programs go in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 in a VM, and I noticed that unlike in Windows, when I minimize a program, it disappears completely and the only way to bring it back is to hit alt-tab or click the Activities link in the upper left corner. Is there any way to make minimized programs appear somewhere onscreen like they do in Windows?

Comment: Don't you have a hidden bar in the bottom or at the left? Try hovering your mouse there.

Comment: Look for a `small` tick-mark next to the icon of running applications. IMHO, it could have been made a bit more obvious.

Comment: I do see a tiny orange dot next to any pinned apps that are currently running in the sidebar, and multiple dots if multiple instances are running. I could have sworn that non-pinned apps never appeared in the sidebar when iI run them, but it looks like now they do - weird!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently they go in the sidebar with my pinned apps; I must not have noticed this before because my screen resolution was so low that there was no room for them!